# Create a spring BeanFactory for custom annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, annotations

I have a use case of creating a spring bean factory that scans Types annotated with specific annotation and create spring beans based on annotation parameters.

Spring beans generated by this bean factory is of different type e.g. Class1, Class2. Multiple instances of theses types can be created with different qualifier.

Finally, I should be able to inject them using @Autiwired, @Inject, etc. annotations in any spring bean.

**Notes:** I need factory to avoid creating so many marker components.

For e.g.
There is an annotation @MyAnnotation that accepts a parameter "Class clazz".

There are two classes annotated with this annotation.

```
@MyAnnotation(clazz = Component1.class) FirstService {}
@MyAnnotation(clazz = Component2.class) FirstComponent {}
@MyAnnotation(clazz = Component1.class) SecondService {}
```

There should be a component that filters classes with this annotation and registers them as a bean of Component1, Component2 and Component1 respectively with custom parameters.

And finally I wanted to inject them in any spring bean like

```
@Autowired
Component1 component1Instance1;

@Autowired
Component2 component2;

@Autowired
Component1 component1Instance2;
```

I tried to implement this using ApplicationEvent, ApplicationContextAware, BeanPostProcessor, etc. But, couldn't achieve.

Kindly provide any hint to make this possible.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate on the problem you are tying to solve, maybe custom annotations is not the right solution? It also seems odd to have the type as part of the annotation, you should be able to defer that for the class you put the annotation on.

Comment: I'm using CouchDb as backend and I'm managing 1 common main database and 1 database per user. So, I wanted to created repositories for main database on application startup and repository factory for user wise database so that I can ask it to return repository for the user request arise from.

Comment: If you have something per user, autowire does not sound right, unless you have a bean that is session scoped. I think you are better of having a factory that can provide the interface that models the customers db-instance. `CustomerDBService CustomerDBProvider.getDatabaseForCustomer(String id)`